# Searching through multiple properties in an object using only one input aka global search

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I am trying to build an universal/global search for an object in reactjs using only one text input.

I tried different approaches, including converting the string into an array and then use it to filter through my object. I managed to make the input search through all the properties, but only one at the time.

```js
const data = [
  {
    name:"Italy",
    title:"Best place for Pizza"
  },
  {
    name:"USA",
    title:"It is a federal state"
  }
]
export class MyApp extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      filteredData:[],
      filter:''
    }
    this.handleSearch.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({
      filteredData:data
    })
  }

  handleSearch = (e) =>{
    const filter = e.target.value;

    this.setState({
      filter
    })
  }
  render(){
    var filteredData = data;
    var searchValue = this.state.filter;
    filteredData = filteredData.filter(country => {
      return['name', 'title'].some(key =>{
        return country[key].toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchValue)
      })
    })

    return (
      <div>
        <input type="search" onChange={(e) => this.handleSearch(e)}/>
        {
          filteredData.map(result =>{
              return <p>{result.name} | {result.title}</p>
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

What I want is to be able to combine properties. For example: I want to be able to type in "Italy best place for..." and still get a result. I don't want to be limited to only type either "Best place for Pizza" or "Italy" to get the entry.

Comment: Is it a type of fuzzy search you're looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make your search do something like this:

```js
const data = [ { name:"Italy", title:"Best place for Pizza" }, { name:"USA", title:"It is a federal state" } ]

let search = (arr, str) => {
 return arr.filter(x => Object.values(x)
  .join(' ')
  .toLowerCase()
  .includes(str.toLowerCase()))
}

console.log(search(data, 'Italy best'))
console.log(search(data, 'USA it is'))
```

The idea is to use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and inside get the values of the object (using [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)) (here we assume they all are strings) and combine them (via [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)) into one string. Then use [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to search inside of it.

Comment: That is brilliant! It works perfectly. One question would be if there is any way to be able to type criteria in any order? For example title+name. (A bit of a stretch from what I asked, I know. It isn't a must for me, more like a nice to have) Thank you!

Comment: Yes it is somewhat different but you can also add the fields again and switch their position. Like reverse the array so title is now first and name 2nd. It can get hairy but in most scenarios would work. If this answer has helped you please make sure you mark it so others can find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is best practice or not, but when I ran into a similar problem I just kept chaining my `.filter()` functions to each other, with each filter searching through a different property.

```js
filteredData = filteredData.filter(country => {
    return country['name'].toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchValue)
      }).filter(country => {
    return country['title'].toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchValue)
    })
```

It works, but doesn't look as pretty.